Best resources for families in 2024 to learn about investing and other areas of personal finance
I did not see any current threads for this, so I wanted to post it myself:
Given the quickly changing state of finance for the American family, what are some of the best resources for people to use to learn how to budget, calculate costs and returns accurately, etc.?

Soliciting for resources and for opinions is off topic.

Alas, Littleadv is correct. Stack Exchange is about actionable answers to specific questions, and requests for off-site resources are explicitly out of scope. But really, things haven't changed much, if at all, in the past decade or three; any resources which were good then remain good now. This doesn't have to be complicated or sophisticated.


Given the quickly changing state of finance

Many first principles of finance are timeless and despite the noise, not much has really changed.  If anything many tools have made personal finance easier.
Here are somethings that you brought up:

budget

Budgeting is a skill and there are a wide variety of tools out there to help.  However, pen and paper still work and it can be used as a first step.  The key is to intentionally create a plan to spend the money you will be making in the next month or year with both you and your spouse/partner in agreement.
Some couples use budgeting apps. I like google sheets as it is easy to share with my wife, do math, and I have a good workflow.  Additionally it helps me create both a monthly and a yearly budget which is important to us.
However, the tool doesn't matter.  What matters if both can agree on a budget and stick to it.

calculate costs

This one doesn't make much sense to me.  I am not sure what you are looking for here.

calculate returns

Again this one does not make much sense as how is this actionable?  Lets say you bought a home in 2005 for 225K, a few years later its market value is 130K.  Why does it matter if you calculate the return?  The only question is how do you react to what the market is giving you.

What about crypto, forex, etc...

There are always going to be charlatans/fraudsters selling their wares in order to separate you from your money.  In the early 1900s people used to convince the naïve to buy shares of bridges, thus originating the saying "I have a bridge to sell you".   Forex and crypto are just instances of such.  Heck even the current AI craze has some elements of fraud to it.

How about a good thing?

One tool that I am loving, and have no affiliation with, is this tax estimating web site.  For most households in the US standard income tax withholding does not workout well.  Either they get a massive amount of money back, or owe a hefty sum.  The first is an interest free loan to the government, and the second may even be desirable as you are taking an interest free loan from the government.  However the later has to be planned for and may invoke some fees resulting in a higher tax rate.
It sucks finding out, a few days before the April 15th deadline, that you owe over 10K in taxes and have not planned for it.
One can use the website, and their paychecks to anticipate how much they will owe the IRS and can adjust their withholding as desired.
For the record, I conduct this exercise several times throughout the year and have a goal of owing or getting a return of less than 1,000.  I am not always successful as it is hard work.

How about an example of older being better?

One of the best predictors of future returns, despite the disclaimer, is looking at a fund's 3, 5, and 10 year return.  Investing is not complicated and web sites make it very easy to compare data.
One approach to investing is throw all your money into an S&P500 fund.  You will pay low costs and get good returns.

Great answer; budgeting, simple tax awareness, pragmatic investment suggestion, and avoidance of scam / gambling "investment" cons.
